# Do we have a plan to change to new Theme

Tags: discussion, layout

Like Stackoverflow, this site has any plan to change to the new UI?

Any discussions are going on about that?

Comment: Is this something we actually get a choice about? I thought they just rolled it out on SO, and it may or may change here at some point in the future. I don't know that there's anything we, as users, can change.

Comment: Not our choice, it'll come down to what SE does decide to do - if they roll out a consistent design style for the network. If I had to put money on it, I'd say yes.

Comment: I hope not, I really dislike the new theme :(

Comment: If you're referring to the new top bar, you might want to take a look at my stylesheet for [a better top nav bar](https://georgegarside.com/blog/stack-exchange/better-top-nav-stack-overflow/). (cc @chx)

Comment: @grgarside You are my savior.

Answer (score 4):

How strict are you being with the definition of the word "plan"? The new nav will eventually roll out to the rest of the network, but it's not a super high priority and there's currently no solid timeframe for it to happen. It's what we would have called ["in 6-8 weeks"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514/) before we retired that joke.

(For anyone who has no idea what this question is referring to, just visit [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), or for the detailed backstory, see [this Meta SO post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update).)

Comment: Awww.. , My personnal opinion is it will be good if SO has  a unique identity